# Как сделать, что бы цвет элемента listView в определенной позиции был другого цвета

Tags: android, listview

У меня есть класс CustomView:

```
public class CustomView extends View  {

private String[] hoursList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours); 
private ListView listView;
private HourAdapter hourAdapter;
private MinuteAdapter minuteAdapter;
private DayOfTimeAdapter dayOfTimeAdapter;
public static int middlePosition;

public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_test, viewGroup);

   
        listView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.hours_list);
        hourAdapter = new HourAdapter(context, hoursList);
        listView.setAdapter(hourAdapter);

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                                         @Override
                                         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                                          middlePosition = firstVisibleItem+1;

                                         }
                                     }
        );
```

и класс адаптера:

```
public class HourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater lInflater;
        private String[] hoursValueList;
    
        public HourAdapter(Context context, String[] hoursValueList{
            lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.hoursValueList = hoursValueList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
          if (view == null) {
                view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }
    
            TextView textHours = view.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
            textHours.setText(hoursValueList[position]);
            
            if (position == CustomView.middlePosition) {
              view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_color);
            }
    
            return view;
        }
    }
```

как сделать, что бы любой элемент, который попадает в среднюю позицию, был другого цвета?

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Comment: Может лучше готовую библиотеку использовать, их довольно [много разных понаписано](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=Timepicker+android&s=&type=Repositories). И у вас же, судя по коду в вопросе, есть какая то реализация подсвечивания среднего элемента, что с ней не так?

Comment: готовую библиотеку мне использовать нельзя. при коде, который есть сейчас, окрашиваются все элементы

Comment: Скорее всего это из за того, что нужно не только закрашивать какую то позицию, но и восстанавливать цвет для других позиций, то есть код должен быть примерно таким: if (позиция = закрасить) { закрасить } else { восстановить основной цвет }

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду так: ?                                                                                                                                       ' if (position == TimePickerView.middlePosition) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_color);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_select_color); '
        }

Comment: Да так, это самая явная у вас ошибка в коде, тут дело в том, что элементы списка не создаются каждый раз заново, а повторно используются с других позиций, поэтому при заполнении элемента нужно позаботится, чтобы все виджеты получили новые значения. В вашем коде, если виджет получает закрашеный цвет, то незакрашенным он уже никогда не станет. если проблемы все ещё будут, то они могут быть связаны только с определением самой позиции, которую нужно закрасить.